# How to ensure that future Implementations of an Interface will also extend a particular Class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring, class-design

I have an ***abstract class*** and two ***final classes*** that extend it.

The ***abstract class*** is also an implementation of an ***interface***.

Now I have to remove one of the two *child classes* and **add an interface** so that people can still come in with their own implementations.

But I need to ensure that whoever implements the **new interface** is going to extend the **existing abstract class**. It is required because otherwise it won't be functioning.

Is there a way to achieve that, or I can only document an implementation requirement?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your goal is to impose *restrictions* by providing a **single point of extension** in your API and at the same time *expose* your *top-level abstractions* to end-users in order to allow them to utilize these abstractions in the code.

You can achieve both accessibility and control over the class hierarchy with **sealed classes and interfaces** introduced with **Java 17**.

#### Sealed

The feature was finalized by [JEP 409](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409).

> A **sealed** *class* or *interface* can be extended or implemented only by
> those classes and interfaces **permitted** to do so.

I.e. if **sealed** modifier is being applied to a *class*/*interface* it implies that only *classes* or *interfaces* listed in the **permits** *clause* of its declaration are allowed to *extend*/*implement* this *class*/*interface*.

The **permits** *clause* needs to be always present in the declaration of a **sealed** *class*/*interface*. And for all *subclasses*/*subinterfaces* mentioned in the **permits** *clause* of their *parent* it's mandatory to *extend*/*implement* the **sealed** the *parent* **directly**.

In turn, every *subclass*/*subinterface* has to be declared either:

- **sealed** (with it own **permits** *clause* etc.);
- **non-sealed** - a modifier that "breaks the seal" and turns this child into a normal *class*/*interface* which can be extended without any restrictions;
- **final** (only for classes).

Note that both **sealed** and **non-sealed** modifiers play well with **abstract** modifier. Which is particularly useful for this task.

> A class which is *sealed or non-sealed may be **abstract***, and have
> abstract members. A sealed class may ***permit subclasses** which are
> **abstract***.

#### Implementation

The idea is to make both ***interfaces*** (existing and the one that needs to be implemented by the end-user) and existing ***abstract class*** `sealed` to impose restrictions on their extension.

Existing ***final class*** will remain to be `final`.

The **extension point** will be represented by a `non-sealed` ***abstract class***, which extends the existing *abstract class* and implements the *interface* that defines a contract for *user-specific behavior*.

[image]

With this approach, you can prevent the **critical behaviour** defined by the `Base` *interface* and `Root` class from being implemented in an undesired way, by marking these methods inside the `OpenChild` *class* with `final` modifier.  And at the same time provide a contract for *user-specific behavior* which all *custom classes* are expected to conform to.

That how it might look in the code:

```java
public sealed interface Base permits Root {
    // critical behaviour
    void m1();
    void m2();
}

public sealed abstract class Root implements Base
                            permits ClosedChild, OpenChild {
    // critical behaviour
    public void m1() {} // default implementation
}

public final class ClosedChild extends Root { // can't be extended further
    // critical behaviour
    public void m2() { /* custom implementation */ }
}

public sealed interface Outer {
    // end-user-specific behaviour
    void m3();
    void m4();
}

public non-sealed abstract class OpenChild extends Root implements Outer {
    // critical behaviour
    final public void m1() { super.m1(); }                 // locked
    final public void m2() { /* custom implementation */ } // locked

    // has to be implemented by the end user
    public abstract void m5(); // + methods declared by Outer
}
```

#### Alternatives

If you are using an *earlier version* of Java and therefore can't utilize **sealed feature**, then unfortunately you need to make a *choice* between the ability to **control** the extension of your top-level abstractions and **accessibility** of these abstractions to the end-users.

As a partial solution, you can **hide** from the end-user everything apart from the existing **final class** `ClosedChild` and **extension point** `OpenChild`.

In order to do that, all the *classes* and *interfaces* mentioned above have to reside in a ***separate package***. *Classes* `OpenChild` and `ClosedChild` must be marked as `public`. *Interfaces* `Base`, `Outer` and *abstract class* `Root` have to be ***package private***, i.e. they will be visible to `OpenChild` and `ClosedChild`, but their behaviour will accessible from everywhere.

**Note:** methods declared inside the `Base` *abstract class* in order to make them assemble to the end-user must be `public`, all methods in interfaces are public by default even the interface itself package private.

An example of this approach in the JDK is a package private abstract class `AbstractStringBuilder`, which is not publicly accessible. And its `public final` subclasses `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` share its behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't have the chance to try what you said yet. I will get to this in the next week and give some feedback. I will need a solution for both 17 and earlier versions.

Comment: @VanilMar Did apply these approaches to your problem? If yes, can you please share whether you were able to achieve the desired result or not.